# publish item remotely using c#

Tags: webapi

For testing purposes we would like to create publish and remove some items in Sitecore using a remote testing- client in C#. Sitecore.Services.Client api seems the most logical way to create and delete items.

But how can I publish an item remotely?

Comment: I assume you are not using the new Publishing Service yet?

Comment: Publishing Service is Sitecore 8.2 only right?

Comment: Yep. Was asking because it is a separate service that you should be able to trigger through a rest api (although I haven't done that myself yet)

Comment: Thats a good observation. Surely something we have to consider after upgrading.

Comment: An update on this topic, we have created a module that implements a secured Publish method using SSC. https://www.nishtechinc.com/en/Blog/2019/July/SscPublish

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy option would be to create your own webapi controller and create an action that does the publish, using the Sitecore API: `Sitecore.Publishing.PublishManager.PublishItem(...)` You can pass the item id as a parameter and fetch it from the master database. Other options for the Publish function can be parameterized as well, depending on how flexible you want/need it.

Just be careful that not everyone can start publishing your items, think about security ;)

As you are using the SSC, it should be possible to add custom actions to it: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/sitecoreservicesclient/use_the_restful_api_for_the_entityservice

Edit: apparently Mike Robbins already blogged on how to add a custom action to your SSC: https://mikerobbins.co.uk/2015/03/20/sitecore-entity-service-ssc-custom-controller-action/ - so you can create a custom action and use the Publish method from the Sitecore API in it.

Some info from the blog:

> Entity Service is very flexible allowing you to extend the service
> controller with additional actions. To add an additional action it is
> as simple as adding a new function to the service controller, and
> decorating it with an ActionName and the action type such as HttpGet
>
> If you like the repository pattern that Sitecore have put in place
> with Entity Service using the IRepository interface
> and rather keep all the logic of my controller in a single place (in
> the repository): update the repository to include the extra functional
> we want to add to the Entity Service.
>
> With custom controller actions in Entity Service, the routing is
> configured to respond to
> {Controller-Namespace}/{Controller}/{ID}/{CustomActionName}. If you do
> not include in an ID  in the URL, Entity Service will not resolve to
> your custom controller action. Uou can then call your controller by
> using the prefixed of “/sitecore/api/ssc”.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Extending an existing service is a nice option! –