# Is it possible to trigger publishing from Sitecore Item WebAPI

Tags: item-web-api

Is it somehow possible to trigger publishing of the item via Sitecore item web api?
I found how to get items and similar things, but can't find the way to publish it.
For instance, to get an item I would write something like that:

CallSitecoreAPI(@"http://MyHost.com/-/item/v1/?sc_itemid={A60ACD61-A6DB-4182-8329-C957982CEC74}")

What would be a syntax to publish this item from Master to Web database via item WebAPI?

PS. We use Sitecore 7.5
Here it's said that I would need to create a custom action in a controller: [publish item remotely using c#](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/3525/publish-item-remotely-using-c)
Is there simplier approach? I just need to trigger this publication once to fix some bad data in our database and then forget about that script.

Comment: If you have access to the CM why would you need a script for that? If you need to publish multiple items only once, you can use Sitecore PowerShell Extensions - https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/.

Comment: Yeah, I know about PowerShell Extension. Don't really like that idea, because it would require installation on Production environment which could create too much bureaucracy which I don't like...